# IntelliJ SASS file watcher doesn't detect changes in SCSS file

Tags: intellij-idea, sass, file-watcher

I have a `style.sass` file that `@use`s several `_*.sass` partials. That was all working fine. Now I added a `_*.scss` file (it just contains a map, so I wanted it to be multiline), but editing that file does not trigger a rebuild of the `style.sass` file. I tried adding a SCSS file watcher too, since I'm not sure how IntelliJ decides what to watch, but that didn't help.

It works fine using Dart-SASS's `--watch` argument. How do I make IntelliJ do the same?

(Although it's a Play project, I'm using IntelliJ's file watchers because I wanted to be able to use `@use`, so I needed Dart SASS.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The watcher can only listen to changes in files of same type (either `SASS` or `SCSS`), depending on the watcher settings, so you can't make the watcher work for both `.scss` and `.sass` files at the same time unless you use a custom [scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html) with both `.sass` and `.scss` files included and set **File Type:** to **Any**:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! It looks like `file[site]:*/*.sass||file[site]:*/*.scss` has done the trick.